# The argument type 'List<string>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I'm trying to build a quiz app with flutter but i ran into a problem. I have my main.dart and question.dart file. I've created a questionText in the question.dart file through a constructor but i also created a question list in main.dart. Now i'm confused as to how to return my question.

Here's my main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quiz_app/question.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 var _questionIndex = 0;

void _answerQuestion() {
  setState(() {
  _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
});
print(_questionIndex);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var questions = ['What is your fav color?', 'What is your fav animal?'];

return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Quiz App"),
    ),
    body: Column(
      children: [
        Question(
          questions[_questionIndex],
          questionText: [_questionIndex.toString()],
        ),
        // ignore: deprecated_member_use
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Answer 1'),
          onPressed: _answerQuestion,
        ),
        // ignore: deprecated_member_use
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Answer 2'),
          onPressed: _answerQuestion,
        ),
        // ignore: deprecated_member_use
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Answer 3'),
          onPressed: _answerQuestion,
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Then here's my question.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class Question extends StatelessWidget {
  String questionText;

Question(String question, {Key? key, required this.questionText})
    : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Text(questionText);
 }
}
```

The big problem i have is that the app doesn't return the question in my list. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
questionText: [_questionIndex.toString()],
```

The Question Widget requires the questionText to be an String. But here you are giving it a list of Strings. By putting the string inside brackets you turn it into a list of strings.

If you remove the brackets should work:

```
questionText: _questionIndex.toString(),
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the `questionText` as a String Data type. But in the `MaterialApp` widget, in which you are calling the Question class, you gave a second argument as `[_questionIndex.toString()]`. As per you code, _questionIndex is an `Integer`, so that when you convert it into String, It will be like '1' or '2' or '3' something like that!
So, here you giving the List of String which will be only contain the one string and that is your `questionIndex`, so this will give error as you defined the questionText as `String` but you are assigning it a `List Of Strings`.

You should replace your

```
questionText: [_questionIndex.toString()],
```

with

```
questionText: _questionIndex.toString(),
```

I recommend you to apply some changes in your code to improve the code :

If you want to display the question of the number along with the question then replace your code in `Question` class, like this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class Question extends StatelessWidget {
  final questionNumber;
  final questionText;

Question(this.questionNumber, this.questionText);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   return Text('${questionNumber.toString()} $questionText');
 }
}
```

Changes in the  `MaterialApp` widget :

```
...
 body: Column(
      children: [
        Question(
          _questionIndex+1,
          questions[_questionIndex],  
        ),
...
```

Comment: This absolutely worked. I appreciate you!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Hi @AdeolaAdesina, If this worked for you then accept the answer (tick on the left side of the answer) so that others can easily know !